# Query to show results without hits

Tags: php, mysql

My project is an eventpage where volunteers can set if they are available or not to help on that event.
An admin page shows the list of events and whether there are people available or not.

The problem is that I want to let volunteer show that he/she did not yet confirm the availability. The current result is that the not confirmed event is not shown at volunteer 2 when volunteer 1 allready confirmed.

Simple database lay-out

```
events:
e_id e_name
1    Test event
2    Party

availability
a_id    v_id    e_id    avail
1       1       1       1
2       1       2       2
3       2       1       1

volunteers:
v_id    name
1       abc
2       xyz
```

As you can read out, volunteer 2 did not yet confirm his/her availability to event 2.

I now have the following code (PHP and MySQL) to read out the events and availability:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM events LEfT JOIN availability ON events.e_id = availability.e_id WHERE availability.v_id is NULL OR availability.v_id = $v_id " ;
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    echo('<table border="0" width="100%" name="events">');
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
        {
        echo('<tr><td><h2>');
        echo $row["e_name"];
        echo('</h2>);
        echo('<br>Available? ');
            if ($row["besch"] == 1 ) { // 1 = present
            echo('<img src="img/valid.png"><br>');
            }
            elseif ($row["besch"] == 2 ) { // 2 = absent
            echo('<img src="img/unvalid.png"><br>');
            }
            else {  // ? = No information in database
            echo('<img src="img/question.png">&nbsp;* New event!<br>');
            }
            echo ('</td></tr>');
        }
    echo('</table>');
    } else {
    echo ('There are no events.<hr>');
    }
```

The problem is that as soon as a volunteer filled in his/her availability, the event 2 does no longer show up as new to volunteer 2.

The problem in my query is that, as soon as a volunteer files in the availability, according the the query, the availability.v_id is no longer NULL, but neither volunteer n° 2.

(I slightly editted the code to submit on this website: translated my Dutch words to English, removed the ORDER BY from the MySQL Query.... I hope not to have created mistakes that wheren't there ;) )

Comment: What is the exact output that you want to have ? What you exactly want to achieve ?

Comment: The problem is that I want to let volunteer show that he/she did not yet confirm the availability.
The current result is that the not confirmed event is not shown at volunteer 2 when volunteer 1 allready confirmed.

Comment: I am asking that what your query is returning and what you actually want to receive as output of your query?

Comment: in your query WHERE availability.v_id is NULL AND availability.v_id = $v_id should not full filled at simultaniously

Comment: Keyur: The current query shows only event 1 for volunteer 2, while it should also show event 2 while it has not been confirmed.

Comment: Vibha: thx, I just saw the same thing and was editing my post, changed the AND into OR, which gives my the situation described above.